# Differential form of surface integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, surface-integrals, scalar-fields

Considering a scalar field in a plane (pressure vs. location) $P({\rm r})$ where ${\rm r}=(x,y)$ then the following surface integral gives the surface deformation due to the pressure in the elastic half space

$$ \delta = - C \iint_{A} \frac{P({\rm r})}{\|{\rm r}\|}\,{\rm d}A $$

Is there a way to reverse this equation into a differential form. Something like

$$ \nabla^2 \delta = \ldots C\, P(\vec{r})$$

where $\nabla^2 = \ldots \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} \ldots \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y} \ldots \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2} $

In the situations I am looking at I know the shape of $\delta$ and need to find the shape of $P({\rm r})$. Numerically this is very intensive because the discretization of the domain of $\rm r$ results in dense matrix with several thousand elements than need inversion. In a differential form I could try a different approach to solving this problem (using finite differences for example).

<sub>Related similar question: [Proof of Gauss' Law of gravitation without reference to Newton?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/656983/3301)</sub>

Comment: Can you give the source of your equation?  I am having a problem with the meaning of ||r|| .  Anyway, the problem seems to be something like: dz=C*P(x,y)*dx/\dy in differential forms notation.  Where dz is in the normal to the surface coordinates x,y .  Which I also presume moves as z moves?  I think you also need some more boundary conditions; otherwise the whole sheet just floats away.

Comment: This is the so called Bussinesq equation of deformation on the elastic half space due to pressure over an area. $\| r \| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Example usage in eq. (7) in http://www.mae.virginia.edu/NewMAE/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/li_berger_semi_analytical.pdf

Comment: I am not familiar enough with this to offer good advice.  I did find http://nptel.ac.in/courses/105108070/module8/lecture17.pdf  which phrases the Bussinesq equations in differential equation form and then derives some integral forms.  I have problems with the apriori "stress equation" too; is this basically a material property?  Basically, it's looks like a dissipative wave equation to me.  I am more comfortable (not knowledgeable!) with the tensor form of stress analysis.  I look at it as having a physics description given by fundamentals and then matching that to the material properties.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't see the differential form of the pressure deflection relationship. This problem was refined later by H.Love (http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/roypta/228/659-669/377.full.pdf). In reality, I was wondering from a math standpoint how to approach this. There is similar relationship in Gauss' theory of gravity with an integral and differential form $\nabla g=-4\pi G\rho$ (see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/656983/3301)

Comment: Anyhow, you have a surface in 3 space and you want to construct a differential equation consistent over the surface and identify a particular quantity P in the differential equation?  Knowing the intrinsic properties of the surface and the boundary conditions?  Is the surface known in closed form of just a collection of point values?

Comment: Out of order comment (due to the five-minute rule):  I see; my "differential forms" comment was a little off-topic. But I grew quite fond of the discipline while studying differential geometry. Differential forms provide a "universal" framework and also clarify a lot. In your case I think I know how to do what you want; but I need some more info. How about introducing the coordinates for $\delta$;say $\delta(x′y′)$ ,$\delta(r,\theta)$ ? and ||r||; is it distance between a pressure point and displacement or the universal graph r ? I think I know the meaning of the equation but am not sure

Comment: I would think that "pressure" is characterized as a divergence which should be a simple calculation once the material characteristics are known.

Comment: @rrogers yes $r$ is the euclidean distance between the surface element ${\rm d}A$ and the deflection $\delta$ location.

Comment: I think what you want is covered starting at slide 15 of FEM2&3D.ppt at: http://www.rpi.edu/~des/FEM2&3D.ppt   be aware that this site was marked by some at some time as having viruses.  In any case quote:      "If we knew u then we could compute the strains and stresses within the element. But I DO NOT KNOW u!!

Hence we need to approximate u first (using shape functions) and then obtain the approximations for ... (recall the case of a 1D bar)

This is accomplished in the following 3 Tasks in the next slide"